# How to Auto-Update Database according to date?

Tags: sql-server

how to auto update the database according to date?

```
Message ID |   Message   |    StartDate   |   EndDate    | Status
     1     |    Hello    |    07/7/2012   |   08/7/2012  | Expired 
     2     |      Hi     |    10/7/2012   |   12/7/2012  | Ongoing
     3     |   Hi World  |    11/7/2012   |   18/7/2012  | Pending
```

How to auto update the status according to the date today?

More information : I'm using SQL-Server Management Studio. Sorry for not stating.

Comment: Technical Question: huh?

Comment: Well, this is generally pretty straight forward but there is not near enough information here to answer you.  We need to know what ORM/mechanism you're using for your data model, what database engine you're using, and that's at a minimum.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive No kidding! +1 for that ... :)

Comment: "I have a problem. How to fix it?" Can you please be more specific? Provide some background, some code sample and more important, what have you tried?

Comment: I thought the image was uploaded but it failed. Therefore I type in the table myself

Comment: Judging from the original tags you put (C# and ASP.NET), I would recommend pulling the `StartDate` and `EndDate` from your database in the code-behind and then display it as `Expired`, `Ongoing`, or `Pending` using whatever logic you would have used on the database side. This may be a better option for you since you may otherwise need to schedule jobs, which means that the `Status` would not always be up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way for the table to update itself.  You should consider scheduling a Job in SQL Server.

See this MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx)

The job would run daily and consider each row and update the status where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to create store procedure that update records on your table based on your date time and create SQL server job then schedule it on your desired time when to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a SP that sets the status to "Expired" for all messages that have `EndDate > GETDATE()` and schedule it using a job in Sql Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateMessages
AS

UPDATE Messages SET Status = 'Expired' WHERE EndDate > GETDATE()

GO
```